# Replacement for spring-cloud starter packages starting from springboot 2.3.0.M1

Tags: spring-cloud

with spring-cloud packages being not supported(Required Spring Boot >= 2.0.0.RELEASE and <= 2.3.0.M1 error message displaying in spring initializr page) in springboot 2.3.0 onward how can we develop springboot application involving discovery server, proxy gateway, oauth2 packages.

Comment: snapshots should work, spring cloud will have a milestone this month.

Comment: actually no, when try to add dependencies for 2.3.0(SNAPSHOT) version , no cloud dependency is enabled and there is a message "Required Spring Boot >= 2.0.0.RELEASE and < 2.3.0.M1"

Comment: yeah, that will eventually get worked out.